# draw mat-table angular values from oracle query

Tags: oracle, angular2, angular-material

I'm trying to draw a table using the mat-table. the data goes in the following form:

values of displayedColumns must take from array:

metaData:Array(2)[0:{name: "USERNAME"},1:{name: "SCORE"},2:{name: "YEAR"}]

values of dataSource must take from array such ass:

rows:Array(3)0:{USERNAME: "asdasdas", SCORE: 123123, YEAR: 2015},1:{USERNAME: "asdasdqw", SCORE: 123123, YEAR: 2016},2:{USERNAME: "asdasdwe", SCORE: 234124, YEAR: 2017}.

please help me do this.

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Импортируем `MatTableModule` в `app.module.ts`:

```typescript
// app.module.ts

import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....,
        MatTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Используем компонент `mat-table` в приложении:

```js
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

type Score = {
    USERNAME: string;
    SCORE: number;
    YEAR: number;
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public displayedColumns: ReadonlyArray<string> = [
        'USERNAME',
        'SCORE',
        'YEAR'
    ];

    public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Score>([{
        USERNAME: 'asdasdas',
        SCORE: 123123,
        YEAR: 2015
    }, {
        USERNAME: 'asdasdqw',
        SCORE: 123123,
        YEAR: 2016
    }, {
        USERNAME: 'asdasdwe',
        SCORE: 234124,
        YEAR: 2017
    }]);
}
```

И шаблон `app.component.html`:

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="USERNAME">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>USERNANE</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.USERNAME }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="SCORE">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SCORE</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.SCORE }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="YEAR">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>YEAR</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.YEAR }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: overthesanity thx a lot. can I take dynamical displayedColumns values from following array? metaData:Array(2)[0:{name: "USERNAME"},1:{name: "SCORE"},2:{name: "YEAR"}]

Comment: @UlugbekDiyarov, `displayedColumns` can only be an array of strings and no, you can't, but you can use `ngIf` in your template

Comment: I'm use `for (let index = 0; index < data.result.metaData.length; index++) {
              this.displayedColumns.push(data.result.metaData[index].name);
            }`